# How to map table at run time?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, mapping, runtime

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE airports (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2 NOT NULL,
);
```

have this class for mapping:

```
@Entity(name = "AirportEntity") 
@Table(name = "airports", schema = "public", catalog = "postgres") 
public class AirportsEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    /* getter and setter */ 
}
```

How can I set `catalog = "postgres"` on run time? I want `catalog = parameter`, where `parameter` set on run time.

PS. I deleted `schema = "public", catalog = "postgres"` on table annotation and in `hibernate.cfg.xml` set `<property name="hibernate.connection.url"></property>` at run time, 
(`configuration.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:postgresql://" + ip + ":" + port + "/"+ catalog);`) and all work:)

Comment: Seems a bit odd, typically a database is a rather static thing. What's your usecase / problem?

Comment: i have several catalogues, which have identical structure tables and I need use one of them on runtime.
`calatog1.airports`,
`catalog2.airports`,
`catalog3.airports`
....

Comment: So disregard my comment. My understanding was that you wanted to access *different* catalogues at runtime.